# How can I get perl to correctly pass a command line argument with multiple arguments and complex file paths (spaces and symbols)?

Tags: perl, cmd

I have a small perl script which collects file paths from an excel file and passes them through the command line to perltex which then compiles a pdf based on the files and paths chosen.

My problem is that the moment I introduce more complex file paths (which is necessary based on the network setup of the final user pool) perltex fails to find the file paths, cutting them at the space.

A MWE is a follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.14.2;

use Text::Template;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use utf8;
use charnames qw( :full :short );
use autodie;

my $row = 5;
my $col = 15;
my $File = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Reporting-Static/Input-test1.xlsm";
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();             
my $workbook = $parser->parse($File);
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet("Input");
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $col);
my $Filename = $cell->Value();

my $texfile = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Reporting-Static/file.tex"; 
# can't find this file if there are spaces in the address
system("perltex", "--latex=pdflatex", "--nosafe", "--jobname=$Filename", "$texfile");

if ( $? == -1 )
 {
   print "command failed: $!\n";
 }
 else
 {
   printf "command exited with value %d", $? >> 8;
 }

 exit;
```

However, the moment I change the folder name to one with spaces eg. "Reporting Static" it fails to find the tex file.

I have read several other posts regarding this on stack exchange and other websites but for whatever reason the proposed solutions do not appear to work for me. I have tried

```
my $texfile = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Reporting Static/file.tex";
my $texfile = C:/Users/me/Desktop/"Reporting Static"/file.tex;
my $texfile = "\"C:/Users/me/Desktop/"Reporting Static"/file.tex\"";
my $texfile = "\"C:/Users/me/Desktop/Reporting Static/file.tex\"";
my $texfile = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Reporting^ Static/file.tex";
my $texfile = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Reporting\^ Static/file.tex";
```

As well as a few other combinations or varioations of the above, all without success. I have also tried replacing the double quote with a single quote so that perl doesn't interpolate the contents.

I have also tried manually typing all of the above into the command prompt to check whether there was a small issue with the way perl passed the commands to the command line but still no luck.

I am aware that I can use the 'dir /X ~1 c:\' command to find system name allocations that avoid spaces but the idea is that the filename and location will be dynamic and change as a funtion of department and site, so I would prefer to avoid trying to write a script which will go and find this pathname and use it to replace all locations using spaces or other special characters.

The final idea that I had is that this problem could be connected ot the way that perltex passes it's arguments yet I am unable to find any documentation (that I can follow...) on the specifics of how this particular aspect of the file functions.

So my questions are, is there something I am missing not metioned in the other answers that I have read regarding how to correctly pass these paths to perltex, is there perhaps some sort of incompatiblity in how I'm trying to go about this, is this more probabl linked to perltex as opposed to perl or cmd or is there something completely different that I am unaware of that is stopping this from working???

EDIT:
from cmd prompt perltex returns a "unable to find path X, please enter another file location". Until now I hadn't really tested retyping the path by by entering 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/"Reporting Static"/file.tex' (no quotes at the beginning) it is subsequently accepted and runs. but initially passing it this path does not work, suggesting that some internal perltex code accepts the inital path differently to being repassed the same path after an error.... not quite sure what to make of this.

EDIT:
The contents of @latexcmdline that I extracted

```
    $VAR1 = [
      'pdflatex',
      '--jobname=--',
      '\\makeatletter\\def\\plmac@tag{AYNNNUVKQVJGZKKPGPTH}\\def\\plmac@tofile{Perl.topl}\\def\\plmac@fromfile{Perl.frpl}\\def\\plmac@toflag{Perl.tfpl}\\def\\plmac@fromflag{Perl.ffpl}\\def\\plmac@doneflag{Perl.dfpl}\\def\\plmac@pipe{Perl.pipe}\\makeatother\\input C:/Users/me/Desktop/PERLTEST/Perl',
      'Modules/RevuedeProjetDB.tex'
    ];
```

This was done by inserting

```
    use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;
write_file 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\PERLTEST\mydump.log', Dumper( \@latexcmdline );
```

before the exec command.

Comment: The code you show will pass the string in `$texfile` to `perltex` as one parameter; in fact you should be using  just `$texfile` instead of `"$texfile"`. It's my guess that `perltex` doesn't like that parameter to contain spaces

Comment: Where can I get a copy of your `perltex.pl`?

Comment: @borodin You can grab perltex.pl here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/perltex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

I initially recommended that you should use [`String::ShellQuote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) but that module is for Linux only so I deleted my answer when I realised that your question was about the Windows system

It seems that there's also a [`Win32::ShellQuote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote) which does the same thing for Windows, so I am renewing my suggestion

As I said before, the issue is that perltex itself doesn't properly handle paths containing whitespace, even if they are correctly passed as a single element of `@ARGV`. I believe the solution is to pass the path *including enclosing quotes*, although I have never been able to test this properly as I have no LaTex installation

Unfortunately, even if I pass `qq{"$texfile"}`, the quotes are still stripped before they reach the target program, so they must be protected in some way

You need the `quote_system` function from that module, which will prepare a list of strings so that they retain any quotation marks

Using a parameter of `quote_system(qq{"$texfile"})` produces the correct result in my tests. It is the equivalent of passing `qq{"\\"$texfile\\""}` but less ugly

So your system call should be like this (with *no* modification to perltex.pl)

I have applied the same principle to `$Filename` as it may well be that this also contains whitespace

```
use Win32::ShellQuote 'quote_system';

system(quote_system(
    'perltex',
    '--latex=pdflatex',
    '--nosafe',
    qq{--jobname="$Filename"},
    qq{"$texfile"},
));
```

---

Okay, well I have a solution of sorts

The issue, as I suspected, is that, although the path is passed as a single string to `perltex.pl`, the latter doesn't handle paths with spaces properly after it has received them

The temporary fix is to hack `perltex.pl`

Line 82 of my version of `perltex.pl` (there is no version number in the source) reads

```
$latexcmdline[$firstcmd] = "\\input $option";
```

If you change that to

```
$latexcmdline[$firstcmd] = qq{\\input "$option"};
```

then all should be well. However this is a solid fix only when it is distributed by the author of `perltex`. Meanwhile I am looking for a nicer solution from the calling side

Comment: @ Borodin I see how this could be a problem xD. I have attempted to apply this temporary fix rapidly but it does not seem to be taking. Though I haven't had a chance to check the calling directories as I may perltex located in multiple locations (I know I shouldn't just haven't got round to cleaning up yet) so I'll be sure to check that first tomorrow and hopefully get back to you then.

Comment: @NzFrancis: Please read my update. You need [Win32::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I think I need to check my notification settings. I have cleaned up my perl installations, tried your hotfix, returned the original perltex file, installed the Win::ShellQuote module and then tried the above code but it still fails to find the correct path and is cutting off at the space. Atleast thanks to you I am now aware of the precise problem but I still don't see how your suggestions aren't working, cause based on your code I can see why they should work...

Comment: @NzFrancis: The file that I've been working with is [perltex.pl](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/scripts/perltex/perltex.pl). Its MD5 checksum is `bd69ec2ff1c121b18247ae0fa54420dc`. You should start debugging perltex: it's not hard. I can talk you through it if you want to go off-band. The problem must be with the contents of `@latexcmdline` when latex itself is executed at line 158 with `exec {$latexcmdline[0]} @latexcmdline`. Just dump the contents of the array there and we will be wiser

Comment: @ Borodin Thanks for your time and effort, I would indeed appreciate a few pointers for debugging perltex (I'll start with dumping its contents as suggested). Though I am not quite sure how to go about getting my own checksum, nor what the MD5 means.

Comment: @NzFrancis: It's simple enough to google MD5. [Here's the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). There are numerous MD5 calculators that will evaluate the checksum for a file, just to make sure that you are using the same one as I am. Again, just google "md5 calculator" and pick one that you like. As for debugging perltex, please first make sure that the update to my answer isn't sufficient; I fondly hope that you can get away without changing `perltex.pl` at all. Otherwise, it's a matter of adding `print` statements to see the intermediate values as they are calculated

Comment: @ Borodin - Indeed I should have started there before asking. The checksum for the perltex file  have is '30B54F23CF6801B72511B896DAB22C26' calculated from an online calculator. I should perhaps mention I am using 32-bit versions of everyting, not sure if this has an influence. And as for your other debugging instruction, I tried your updated answer without succes and proceeded to print the contents as suggested. I updated that in my origininal post as an edit on friday, I guess I should have left a comment saying so, I'm still figuring out how all the notifications work xD.

Comment: @ Borodin - Thanks in any case fo your help, I'm going to mark this as accepted as I now know the cause of the problem and how to go about solving it, even it is isn't explicitly fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to solving this problem.

1. Work out how to get the correct arguments into an external
   program.
2. Work out how to do that from a Perl program.

For step 1, I find a program like this to be useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Received ", scalar @ARGV, " arguments:\n";
for (1 .. @ARGV) {
  print "$_: $ARGV[$_ - 1]\n";
}
```

It just explains what arguments it receives on the command line. You can use this in place of "perltex" for testing purposes.

You'll see that if you give it an argument that contains spaces, then that is interpreted as the called program as multiple arguments. The way to get round that is to quote the argument that contains a space. And I seem to remember that Windows insists on double-quotes (for reasons that I can never remember).

So I think that you want this:

```
system('perltex', '--latex=pdflatex', '--nosafe', "--jobname=\"$Filename\"", "\"$texfile\"");
```

I've double-quoted both of the filenames. Of course, those escaped double-quote characters look really ugly, and Perl gives us `qq(...)` to make that look nicer.

```
system('perltex', '--latex=pdflatex', '--nosafe', qq(--jobname="$Filename"), qq("$texfile"));
```

If that's not quite right, then the program I showed earlier will make it easier to find the solution.

**Update:** Borodin's comment below about this making no difference to `$texfile` is accurate. The fact that we're passing a list to `system()` means that the shell isn't involved at all.

Comment: The additional double quotes won't make any difference for `$texfile` -- they are simply stripped off and the target program never sees them -- although it may change how `$Filename` is processed. The thing is that a call to `system` with multiple parameters isn't passed through the shell anyway, so the values retain their individuality

Comment: I agree  that the target program never sees the quotes. But it will get see the contents of `$textfile` as a single argument. That, at least, is what my testing seems to indicate.

Comment: As I said, the multi-parameter form of `system` should keeps the values separate and whole anyway. Do you have a test that shows it splitting a value on whitespace?

Comment: @Dave Cross I tested both of your suggestions without any luck and I can see the utility of the little script you wrote. I've been manually typing the arguments into cmd to test that but even then, perltex doesn't accept the path with space. It never has, but I tested the outputs and perl does pass the desired argument (as far as the code dictates) it's just that this argument still isn't accepted, which is why I'm beginning to think my problem may be more related to perltex than to perl.....

Comment: @Borodin: Agreed. And I have added a comment to that effect. My original testing used `qx(...)` rather than `system()` and I had forgotten the important differences.

Comment: @NzFrancis: Pedantically, I only made one suggestion. The two different syntaxes that I demonstrated are functionally identical. Borodin's comments explain why my suggestion makes no difference to `$texfile`.

Comment: @NzFrancis: I use just `use Data::Dump; dd \@ARGV;` for my test program :)